# TypeError: cannot marshal <type 'numpy.uint8'> objects

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am unable to set parameters to the param server using the following code:

> hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image,
> cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
>
> rospy.set_param("lower_h", hsv[:, :,
> 0].min()) rospy.set_param("lower_s",
> hsv[:, :, 1].min())
> rospy.set_param("lower_v", hsv[:, :,
> 2].min())
>
> print('lower_h = {}\nlower_s =
> {}\nlower_v = {}'.format(hsv[:, :,
> 0].min(), hsv[:, :, 1].min(), hsv[:,
> :, 2].min()))

I am getting the following error:
*`TypeError: cannot marshal <type 'numpy.uint8'> objects`*

In the above code I am able to print the values in the terminal but not set the values in the parameter server. Any help will be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/378231/typeerror:-cannot-marshal-%3Ctype-%27numpy.uint8%27%3E-objects/) by [dee-mikey](https://answers.ros.org/users/69868/dee-mikey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-05-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a difference between uint8 and float64, but it looks like the same cause as [this Question](https://answers.ros.org/question/202046/typeerror-cannot-marshal-type-numpyfloat64-objects/).
I think converting numpy.uint8 to uint8 by doing the following will solve the problem.

```
rospy.set_param("lower_h", hsv[:, :, 0].min().item())
rospy.set_param("lower_s", hsv[:, :, 1].min().item())
rospy.set_param("lower_v", hsv[:, :, 2].min().item())
```

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2021-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0